# Resize all pages without changing geometry

Tags: pdf, geometry, resize

I have composed a 500+ pages book, but now I discovered I have to reduce the size of the page by few millimeters to fit the limits set by the publisher. Because I want to change neither the body of the page (this would force me to fine tune again a lot of floats, huge work) nor the margins, I thought the best solution could be to rescale proportionally the whole page to fit the new dimensions.
Namely, I need to fit a 24.5x17.3 page produced by pdflatex into a 24x17 page in the pdf file to deliver to the publisher. 
Before looking elsewhere (i.e. tools to manipulate the pdf), I was just wondering if there's a way to do the job using some LaTeX package.

Comment: Does it help if you set the `paperwidth` and `paperheight` keys?  I.e., `\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{paperwidth=24cm,paperheight=17cm}` in your preamble?

Comment: You could use pdfpages to rescale the pdf.

Comment: stick `\mag=979` at the top of the file (1000*24/24.5)

Comment: Fine tuning is necessary if you have a lot of floating object (it is a textbook). Everybody who has had some experience with publishing a book knows that you cannot rely on the algorithm alone. I know very well that changing the margin would be the normal thing to do, but this would require spending long hours checking and adjusting

Comment: @anderstood read Frank's notes at the end of "The LaTeX Companion" on how many page breaks were manually adjusted...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My whole life is falling apart... But then the body might not have the right dimensions. Anyway, pdfcrop should do the job easily.

Comment: @david-carlisle About `\mag=979`: should it be used with the 17x25 geometry or with the "new" 17.3x24.5?

Comment: after `\mag=979` all lengths in the document are scaled by 24/24.5 so you would keep your existing specification of a 24.5 and it will come out as 24.  the only thing to watch is any use of `true` dimensions such as `textwidth=8truein` where the `true` prefix means "not affected by `\mag`" but no standard latex classes  use `true` units.

Comment: This is really annoying, but `\mag=979` doesn't seem to work. I guess that the output with/without the command should look exactly the same when I open the produced pdf file with a viewer; I expect the size of the pdf should be adjusted along with the size of the written page, so the margins are not affected. The difference should be noticed only if I print the file without rescaling within a larger papersize. But this is not the case, the bottom of the page is cut and the bottom margin is reduced.

Comment: Stupid question, but are you sure the publisher is OK with the rescaling?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I meant that if an editor specifies both a body dimension and a page dimension, the scaled body might have the right dimensions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Correct about floating images and so forth. This is known behavior (mentioned in the docs). That's why the `novel` class is intended for fiction, not academic works. But the OP has a 500 page book, which for all I know is a murder mystery.

Comment: @Massimo for assorted reasons you may need or want to reset the page size and margins after setting \mag but the important thing is your page breaks and float posn don't change

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Off this site, in other communication, I have already been asked about floats in actual fiction. Force of habit, I guess. There was no need to use floats (in TeX or anything else). Remember there are still many folks who won't use utf-8 and LuaLaTeX to solve font-related problems. Anyway, I primarily put my comment for the benefit of others who find this via search. I learn many things that way. Back to the OP: Probably will have to manipulate the PDF outside of TeX.

Comment: It works in a minimal example, `\mag=979
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,kantlipsum}
\geometry{paperwidth=24.5cm,paperheight=17.3cm,scale=1,showframe}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-20]
\end{document}`. So, if it doesn't work for you, something you've not told us about is conflict. What, we cannot say since you've not provided any code or a reproducible example.

Comment: Do you really want the margins to stay the same? That is, they should not be scaled proportionately? If so, you need to scale everything else by a greater factor and specify the margins in true dimensions. However, this keep-margins-the-same seems inconsistent with your wish to scale everything ....

Comment: @cfr yes, publishers, in general, are sort of picky and strict about their rules concerning margins and printable areas. To me this looks like "something" occured so that the OP now has to fit his stuff onto smaller pages. The rules about margins etc have always been specified in absolute numbers and copy pasted to the tex document, meaning the OP must not/is not supposed to scale these along with the rest of the book.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why I didn't think of this immediately... Just tested, and it works. Hope it solves the problem.

You can print PDF to PDF, and change the size as you print. For example, I have a PDF copy of the local county bus schedule. It has text and images. Does not matter how it was created (probable InDesign), because it is PDF.

My Linux system has the cups-pdf printer. Something similar is on other operating systems. I open the original PDF in my viewer. Then I print it to PDF, choosing a different paper size (and, if necessary, altering other things such as magnification, which affects margins). When I click "print," I wait awhile because the document is large. Then, I get a new PDF at the specified size.

The new PDF has text and images, just like the first. Same pagination, same everything, because all I did was print it. If the original has bookmarks, so does the new print. The only thing changed is the size.

Now, if you are required to present PDF/A or PDF/X, then the printed PDF probably won't have those (or, it might). That can be fixed be re-processing the printed PDF in a program such as Adobe Acrobat Pro. Surely your printer will do that for you (in the context of a 500 page Economics textbook). If your book were a print-on-demand fantasy novel, then the printer wouldn't do it for you (at least, not for free, but at low cost).

The original question asked about a LaTeX package. Not necessary. No need to re-work the *.tex file.

Comment: Why bother with the cups-pdf bit at all, then? Why not just have the publisher do it in Acrobat Pro?

Comment: @cfr Exactly! That's why I originally took this question facetiously (comments since removed). I could not imagine that for something of this nature, the publisher wouldn't "just do it" automatically. But for the benefit of later arrivals who find this by search, I thought the simplest answer would be appropriate. On the other hand, in the world of self-publishing, the author and publisher are one and the same. The print service merely prints it.